# Unity baked lighting - blotchy shadows, bleeding and/or stiching

Tags: unity

I have spent days trying to get baked lighting to look good. I use a simple low-poly style. No matter what I do, I get this type of effect (blotchy shadows and odd dark lines):

[image]

[image]

Here are my settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Baking a scene already takes around 4 hours, not sure I can increase the resolution any more without Unity crashing during the bake. Am I doing something wrong? Feel like Ive tried everything.

Comment: Have you tried stitching-together UV charts along the dark lines you're seeing? That can help you get lighting continuity across the edge. Obviously you can't unify every seam, but getting the most prominent/illuminated ones can help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, ambient occlusion is your culprit. In general, baking usually takes quite a long time; this is why render farms exist.

Comment: unfortunately ive tried without it already =/ same result.

Comment: Unity doc recommends 100 samples for indirect lighting. This will DRASTICALY reduce bake time. Also compressing your lightmap can introduce "unwanted visual effects" Please refer to the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProgressiveLightmapper.html)

Comment: Ive read every doc there is, and tried every combination of settings. As I said, I've tried everything I can think of...